# Coefficients of log-transformed outcome

Tags: regression, inference, interpretation, log-linear

I would like to know what is the appropriate word for regression coefficients of log-transformed outcome(y) after taking the anti-log of regression coefficients.

It is not an odds ratio or risk ratio. So I would like to know the appropriate name for these estimates after taking the anti-log of regression coefficients. Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually interpret regression as a conditional mean of $y$. But because $y$ is logged, it's the conditional arithmetic mean in logscale. In other words, since $$\mathbb{E}[\ln y \vert x+1,z] - \mathbb{E}[\ln y \vert x,z]= \left[ a + b \cdot (x+1) + c \cdot z \right] - \left(a + b \cdot x + c \cdot z \right) = b,$$

then $b$ is the change in expected $\ln y$ associated with a one-unit increase in $x$. Some interpret that as an additive change in the conditional geometric mean of $y$.

If you want to get back to levels from logs, $$\mathbb{E}[y \vert x+1,z] = \exp \{a + b \cdot (x+1) + c \cdot z \} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\varepsilon)],$$ where $\varepsilon$ is the residual.

You can simplify that as
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[y \vert x+1,z] &= \exp \{a + b \cdot (x+1) + c \cdot z \} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\varepsilon)] \\
&= \exp \{a + b \cdot x + c \cdot z\} \cdot \exp \{b\} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\varepsilon)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[y \vert x,z] \cdot \exp \{b\} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\varepsilon)]
\end{align*}$$

You can express that as

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}[y \vert x+1, z]}{\mathbb{E}[y \vert x, z]} = \exp \{b\}.$$

That is the multiplicative change in expected $y$ associated with a 1 unit increase in $x$, keeping $z$ fixed. It is an effect on the conditional *arithmetic* mean of $y$.

For example, if $b=-.04$ then $\exp(-0.04)=.96 < 1$, so the mean of $y$ shrinks.

This will be similar, though not identical, to an exponentiated slope coefficient you would get from a heteroskedasticity-robust Poisson model, which shares that interpretation. People call those incidence-rate ratios.